# python package: can't import a class from working directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

In my current working directory is a sub-directory `cpuimlearn`, having the following structure:

```
$ tree cpuimlearn
cpuimlearn
├── AdaBoostM1.py
├── DECOC.py
├── DOAO.py
├── factory.py
├── FocalBoost.py
├── ImECOC.py
├── __init__.py
└── SAMME.py

0 directories, 8 files
```

The file `factory.py` implements a class `FAC` such that:

```
class FAC:

    def __init__(self):

        pass
    ...
```

So all other files import this class. For example, `AdaBoostM1.py` imports the class like so:

`File: AdaBoostM1.py`

```
from factory import FAC
fac = FAC()
....
```

Strangely however, these files cannot import the class. For example:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> 
>>> from cpuimlearn import AdaBoostM1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/gpuimlearn/src/CPU-imLearn/cpuimlearn/AdaBoostM1.py", line 21, in <module>
    from factory import FAC
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'factory'
>>>
```

As can be seen from the new `__pycache__` directory created, `factory.cpython-38.pyc` isn't created as we expect if the module was successfully imported.

This is strange since `factory.py` is available in the direcory, and this implements `FAC` class.

```
$ tree cpuimlearn
cpuimlearn
├── AdaBoostM1.py
├── DECOC.py
├── DOAO.py
├── factory.py
├── FocalBoost.py
├── ImECOC.py
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── AdaBoostM1.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
└── SAMME.py

1 directory, 10 files
```

Comment: `factory.py` was not in the current working directory when you executed `from cpuimlearn import AdaBoostM1`. It looks like the cwd was `~/gpuimlearn/src/CPU-imLearn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have `__init__.py` in your directory, then this directory is treated as a python package.
To import inside python package you need to use relative import

```py
from .factory import FAC
```

or full name import

```py
from cpuimlearn.factory import FAC
```

explanation from python documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

`factory` is not a package.

You'd need to use relative imports:

`from .factory import FAC`

Alternatively:
`from cpuimlearn.factory import FAC`

Comment: Information that `factory` is not a package is not proper. Package in python is name for directory with `__init__.py`. So if you put a directory with `__init__.py` inside another directory with `__init__.py` you will get a package inside the package. I think that you would like to write "`factory` is not a top level package"